# node.js and socket.io - how to keep data flowing from connected to new connected users?

Tags: ios, node.js, sockets

I've following simplistic server:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(1234);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // Incoming
    socket.on('this_user_data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        // Outgoing (to all but socket)
        socket.broadcast.emit('other_user_data', data);
    });
});
```

And client:

```
            var socket = io.connect('', {port: 1234});

            // Incoming
            socket.on('other_user_data', function(data) {
                console.dir(data);
            });

            // Outgoing
            socket.emit('this_user_data', { my : 'data' });
```

This works perfectly. Already connected user gets my_data of the newly connected user.

But new user knows nothing about already connected user.

How do I flow that data towards a newly connected socket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to have the server emit an event to already connected users that a new user just connected, so then they all reply with their data that then goes to the new user, but a simpler solution would be to store user data when they connect, so when a new user connects, all the user's data is just a db query away.

Comment: In that scenario I've to keep track of offline online users in DB. So I will be writing allot to DB.

Comment: I like your proposal, that wouldn't be too hard to create. Just will it overload node.js?

Comment: Use the disconnect event to remove users when they disconnect from the socket server.  You could store the user data in an array (simple enough) but that will limit you if you ever expand (cluster, more physical servers).  If you don't want to store the user's data on connection, try the first way I recommended.  Overload? Doubtful.  How many people do you expect to be using your chat at the same time?

Comment: I want to build a little multiplayer game for practice, I plan to have both free play no login etc, and also sql based user login part. So basically I want to use both of your suggestions :) I had in mind both ways you described btw, I was just making sure that there are no other more weird ways, since node and sockets is so new to me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Save all users' data in memory (or database).
2. When a new client connects, emit a event to retrieve other users' data. just like this:

client:

```
socket.emit('retrieve-other-users-data', {/* SOME DATA */}, function (responseData) {
  // DO SOMETHING WITH responseData
})
```

server:

```
io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {
  socket.on("retrieve-other-users-data", function (requestData, callback) {
    var otherUsersData = getOtherUserData();
    callback(otherUsersData);
  });
})
```